# Copy a row of data in interactive report in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I have an interactive report in oracle apex, which has details of a bug like
bug number
bug description
developer
reviewer
tdd
dtc
mr
etc

I have a copy button for each row with the following code

```
<button class="fa fa-copy copy-row" data-id="#BUG_TRACKER_ID#" id="#BUG_TRACKER_ID#"></button>
```

On clicking this copy button, I am able to retrieve the id. But I am unsure how to get the data of the entire row. The code I used to get the id is as below:

```
var rowId = $(this.triggeringElement).data("id");
console.log(rowId);
```

This id will give me the primary key. Now I want to get the data of the whole row and create a summary from it. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "create a summary of it" ? When you click "copy" do you want the row to be copied (that seems logical) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to copy a row using a button on an interactive report. It is based on the emp sample table. `EMPNO` is the primary key for the `EMP` table.

The DISP_COL_CLASS column is used to show/hide button for certain records (values are "block" and "none"). Button is built using the [button builder](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/button-builder)

#### Hidden Page item

Create hidden page item to hold the value of the selected record. In this case it is `P182_ITEM`

#### Button

```
<button style="display:#DISP_COL_CLASS#" type="button" data-empno="#EMPNO#" class="my-button-js t-Button t-Button--tiny t-Button--success t-Button--stretch">Copy</button>
```

#### Dynamic Action

[image]

##### Action to set Value

[image]

##### Action to copy row

[image]

##### Action to refresh report

[image]